# Как найти точки многоугольника входящий в другой многоугольник?

Tags: javascript, node.js, трассировка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]У меня есть два текстовых файла:
1) reservoirGrid(сетка) - содержит номер ячейки, координаты местности и signh, сообщающий о возможности строить в этом месте(0 или 1);
2)  polygonObjs(полигон) - содержит объекты состоящие из массива координат, которые очерчивают территорию, где нельзя строить.

Мне нужно проверить не пересекаются ли полигоны с сеткой и если пересекаются отметить все точки пересечения, изменив в них переменную signh на 0.

Перебрал уже разные алгоритмы(все на основе трассировки лучей), но результат, сдается мне, не верный. Может кто подскажет, что не так..

```js
const fs = require("fs");

let polygonObjPointsX = [];
let polygonObjPointsY = [];
let dataPointsX = [];
let dataPointsY = [];

let gridMaxPointX;
let gridMinPointX;
let gridMaxPointY;
let gridMinPointY;

let numberPolygon;

let filePolygonObjsTxt = fs.readFileSync("polygonObjs.txt", "utf8");
let fileReservoirGridTxt = fs.readFileSync("reservoirGrid.txt", "utf8");

let polygonObjs = JSON.parse(filePolygonObjsTxt);
let reservoirGrid = JSON.parse(fileReservoirGridTxt);

// У сетки, беру координаты `х` и `у` и сохраняю их в разных массивах
for (let sk = 0; sk < reservoirGrid.length; sk++) {
    dataPointsX.push(reservoirGrid[sk].x);
    dataPointsY.push(reservoirGrid[sk].y);
}

// maxAndMinGridCoordinateValue(dataPointsX, dataPointsY);

// У каждого полигона, беру координаты `х` и `у` и сохраняю их в разных массивах
for (let i = 0; i < polygonObjs.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < polygonObjs[i]["points"].length; j++) {
        polygonObjPointsX.push(polygonObjs[i]["points"][j]['x']);
        polygonObjPointsY.push(polygonObjs[i]["points"][j]['y']);
    }
    numberPolygon = i;
    inPoly(polygonObjPointsX, polygonObjPointsY);
    // preliminaryCheckPoint(polygonObjPointsX, polygonObjPointsY);
    polygonObjPointsX.splice(0);
    polygonObjPointsY.splice(0);
}

// Метод (трассировка лучей) проверяет на принадлежность координат полигона общей "Сетке"
function inPoly(polygonObjPointsX, polygonObjPointsY) {

    for (k = 0; k < polygonObjPointsX.length - 1; k++) {
        let crossings = 0;
        let a;
        for (i = 0; i < reservoirGrid.length; i++) {
            j = i + 1;
            a = i;
            let cond1 = (dataPointsY[i] <= polygonObjPointsY[k]) && (polygonObjPointsY[k] < dataPointsY[j]);
            let cond2 = (dataPointsY[j] <= polygonObjPointsY[k]) && (polygonObjPointsY[k] < dataPointsY[i]);

            if (cond1 || cond2) {
                if ( polygonObjPointsX[k] > (dataPointsX[j] - dataPointsX[i]) * (polygonObjPointsY[k] - dataPointsY[i]) / (dataPointsY[j] - dataPointsY[i]) + dataPointsX[i] ) {
                    crossings++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (crossings % 2 == 1) {
            reservoirGrid[a]['Signh'] = 0; // Меняем/устанавливаем флаг в сетке
            console.log('Координата полигона:  ', polygonObjs[numberPolygon]["points"][k], 'попадает в сетку в точке: ', reservoirGrid[a]);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите пример небольшого кусочка Вашего JSON'a

Comment: из описания  - я не понял что требуется

Comment: На скриншоте я выложил оба файла: polygonObjs - содержит координаты, чьё  пересечение с основной сеткой координат(файл reservoirGrid) я должен обнаружить. При обнаружении вхождения точки полигона в "сетку" я должен изменить значение Signh на 0. Чтобы в сетке была информация о свободной территории (signh либо 0, либо 1)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ расписал подробнее, надеюсь стало понятнее..

Comment: @devoid что значит `полигон пересекается с сеткой`, поясните, лучше рисунком

Comment: @StrangerintheQ В описании задачи, я написал что значит полигон и что значит сетка, может не заметили. По сути мне нужно обнаружить  в каких точках большого многоугольника(сетка) пересекаются с другими многоугольниками(полигонами)

Comment: @devoid описать то описали, но так, что я ничего по прежнему не понимаю,постановки геометрических  задач -  понятнее из изображения, а не из скриншота с цифрами, который на мобильнике кстати не рассмотреть без танцев

Comment: @StrangerintheQ если необходимо, я могу найти картинку "многоугольник в многоугольнике" , но я думаю вы и так это легко можете представить... Что конкретно непонятно, постараюсь как-нибудь по-другому пояснить

Answer (score 1):

Полигоны могут пересекаться, когда ни одна вершина одного не попадает внутрь другого. Простейший случай - пересечение двух прямоугольников в форме креста. Без нахождения пересечений сторон эта задача, в общем случае, не решается.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272179/a-simple-algorithm-for-polygon-intersection